# iOS : cannot delete file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm newbie in iOS. I have a problem.

I log the path of file and I also verify it in Finder. But fileExistsAtPath: return NO, that's why I cannot delete it.

I need help please!!

Here is the code:

```
+ (void)removeImage:(NSString*)imgName {
MyLog(@"%@", [Tool getFileFullPath:imgName]);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)[Tool getFileFullPath:imgName]];
NSLog(@"Path to file: %@", [Tool getFileFullPath:imgName]);        
NSLog(@"File exists: %d", fileExists);
NSLog(@"Is deletable file at path: %d", [fileManager isDeletableFileAtPath:[Tool getFileFullPath:imgName]]);
if (fileExists) 
{
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[Tool getFileFullPath:imgName] error:&error];
    if (!success) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

}
```

Path to file: `/Users/vibolteav/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/FD57CA70-14E4-442D-9CA5-DE7A7AD56A93/Documents/img/2053871632`

File exists: `0`

Is deletable file at path: `1`

Comment: can you please paste the path ?

Comment: is your file located in sandbox?

Comment: is your file readOnly or both read-write? and what code you are using for deleting the file?paste full code

Comment: could you please paste your logs and codes.

Comment: We can't help if you don't give us any code!  :)

Answer (score 1):

for remove file from document directory you use below code:

```
 -(void)removeOneImage:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSLog(@"%@",fullPath);
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
```

}

Comment: Would you share it with us, please? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Document Path..

```
   NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Append File name...

```
  NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]) 
       {
           NSError *error;

           if (![fileManager removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error]) {

           }
       }
```